# How to get one record from firebase in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular2-observables

I'm trying to get one record by uid from my firebase database in Angular 2 app. The problem is that I'm always getting `undefinied` in profile variable. Could you show me correct way to do this? Thanks!
My code:

Profile class

```
export class Profile{
   constructor(public $key:string, public userId:string, public description:string, public avatarUrl: string){
   }

    static parseFromJson({$key, userId, description, avatarUrl}):Profile{
        return new Profile($key, userId, description, avatarUrl);
    }
}
```

Profiles service

```
@Injectable()
export class ProfilesService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  getUserByUserId(userId:string): Observable<Profile>{
    return this.db.list('profiles',{
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'userId',
          equalTo: userId
      }
    }).map(result => Profile.parseFromJson(result[0]));
  }
}
```

Profile component

```
export class ProfileComponent {

  profile: Profile;
  uid: string;

  constructor(private profileService: ProfilesService, private af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => this.uid = auth.uid);
    this.profileService.getUserByUserId(this.uid).subscribe(
        result => {
          this.profile = result;
        }
     );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is an array, you might want to take the first value and return as `Observable`.

> `.first` emits only the first value (or the first value that meets some condition) emitted by the source `Observable`.

```
 getUserByUserId(userId:string): Observable<Profile>{
    return this.db.list('profiles',{
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'userId',
          equalTo: userId
      }
    })
    .first()
    .map(result => Profile.parseFromJson(result));
```